Matrices invariant under rotations are always proportional to the identity?
Is this proof true?
Suppose we have a $3\times 3$ matrix $M^{ab}$ satisfying
$$M^{ab}=R^a\,_cR^b\,_dM^{cd},$$
i.e.
$$M=RMR^T,$$
for all rotations $R\in \mathrm{O}(3)$. Now, if denote representations of this group by their dimension, this matrix is in
$$3\otimes 3=1\oplus 3\oplus 5,$$
corresponding to the decomposition
$$M^{ab}=\frac{1}{3}\delta_{cd}M^{cd}\delta^{ab}+\frac{1}{2}M^{de}\epsilon_{dec}\epsilon^{abc}+\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(M^{ab}+M^{ba}\right)-\frac{1}{3}\delta_{cd}M^{cd}\delta^{ab}\right].$$
The invariance condition then implies that this matrix must, in fact, be in the scalar component, so that
$$M^{ab}=\frac{1}{3}\delta_{cd}M^{cd}\delta^{ab}.$$
In other words, all rotationally invariant matrices are proportional to the identity.
What seems weird to me is that, it ties very strongly the indices $a$ and $b$. For example, suppose $M^{ab}=u^av^b$. Does anyone have a simpler explanation? Something less abstract that gives me more intuition of what is going on. Thank you and sorry for the vague question!

Please clarify if you mean rotations, i.e., elements of $SO(3),$ or rotations combined with inversions, i.e., elements of $O(3).$

You can get a simple proof: since the dimension is odd your matrix has an eigenvalue, so $M$ acts as some scalar $\lambda$ on some line $L$, but since $M$ in invariant by rotation its acts as $\lambda$ on any rotation of this line, so it acts as $\lambda$ on the whole space.

This extends nicely to any odd dimensional space, which is cool! The result is simply not true in even dimensional spaces, right?

In 2 dimensions all rotations commute, so the matrix of any rotation is invariant under rotations.

But if you include inversions, like reflection with respect to the $Y$-axis, then the result remains true.
